# Compute an object's inertia around an arbitrary axis, using its known values for the x, y and z axes

Tags: moment-of-inertia

I need to input inertia data into a bio-mechanical simulation program. I can find inertia data for parts of the human body, around the normal axes.

I know the parallel axis theorem, so I can compute the inertia for the body parts in different locations.

But if the body part is **angled** to the normal axes, can you then compute the inertia, using its known inertia around the x, y and z axes?

Let's say that a human arm and hand has the following inertia values (around its center of gravity)
$$I_x = I_y = 0.3\ kg \cdot m^2$$
$$I_z = 0.02\ kg\cdot m^2$$

This would be the values if the arm is hanging down. But let's say I angle the arm outwards ("abduct" it) by 30°, can I then use $I_x,\ I_y$ and $I_z$ to find the new values? (As the angle increases, the $I_y$ value would gradually fall and reach the old $I_z$ value at 90°. Is there maybe a trigonometric relation for this??) OK,  I am not a physicist, I only do bio-mechanics occasionally :)

**Edit 19/7:**
Just to clarify:
What I wish to find out is how angling of the body parts affects their inertia. To use a diver that is somersaulting forward as an example : If the diver keeps the arms straight down the body, the values given above would be correct. But the diver can reduce his/her inertia by angling the arms outwards. (You sometimes see divers do that in the pike position.) I wish to compute the inertia for different angles, all for rotation forward. I wish to start with just the body part alone. (After that you can apply the parallel axes theorem.)

I wonder if there could exist a simple trigonometric relationship since one can divide the mass into point mass elements? I can't prove this is the correct answer but I plotted $0.3\cos(\alpha) + 0.02\sin(\alpha)$. It would show how the moment of inertia of the arm, for rotation forward (like in somersaulting), would decrease, as the arm is abducted (by $\alpha^{\circ}$). (In this example the arm alone is "somersaulting".) Intuitively it looks "OK".

[image: arm inertia on abduction of arm]

(The other alternative is that this can't be computed. You must make a new measurement. But in the case of the arm (looking a little like a rod), I think at least a reasonable estimate could be computed from the x, y and z values.

But what leads me to believe that it is computable, is that you can input $I_x,\ I_y$ and $I_z$ to computer programs and they can compute rotations along oblique axes.)

Comment: The moment of inertia doesn't change.  Rather, you have to apply the dynamics in a more general fashion.   You can *rotate* the inertia tensor to new coordinates, or you can work with the "diagonalized" tensor directly.  [This article](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newtonhtml/node64.html) looks like a decent *introduction* to the topic, and the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#The_inertia_tensor) has a bit more.  But you'll need to dig deeper than what's in those articles in order to use the information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, the rotational inertia of a rigid body is fully characterized by an *inertia tensor*, which has 6 independent variables: $I_{xx}$, $I_{yy}$, $I_{zz}$, $I_{xy}$, $I_{yz}$, $I_{zx}$. The three diagonal terms can be calculated from moments of inertia about the x,y,z axes (which are $I_x$, $I_y$, $I_z$ in your notation):

$I_{xx} = \frac{I_y + I_z - I_x}{2}$; $I_{yy} = \frac{I_z + I_x - I_y}{2}$; $I_{zz} = \frac{I_x + I_y - I_z}{2}$

Unfortunately, the three non-diagonal terms $I_{xy}$, $I_{yz}$, $I_{zx}$ **cannot** be calculated from $I_x$, $I_y$, $I_z$; they are independent quantities that must be measured separately. However, these terms are often zero when the object is symmetric: if there is reflective symmetry in the yz-plane, then $I_{xy} = I_{zx} = 0$; if there is reflective symmetry in the zx-plane, then $I_{yz} = I_{xy} = 0$. I suspect both of these are true for a human arm, to a good enough approximation for your purposes.

Once you know all the components of the inertia tensor, you can calculate the moment $I_n$ about an arbitrary unit vector $  \begin{pmatrix}
    n_x\\
    n_y\\
    n_z
  \end{pmatrix}$ using
$I_n = (I_{xx} + I_{yy} + I_{zz}) - I_{nn}$, where:

\begin{equation*}
  I_{nn} =
  \begin{pmatrix}
    n_x\\
    n_y\\
    n_z
  \end{pmatrix}^T
  \begin{pmatrix}
    I_{xx}&I_{xy}&I_{xz}\\
    I_{yx}&I_{yy}&I_{yz}\\
    I_{zx}&I_{zy}&I_{zz}
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    n_x\\
    n_y\\
    n_z
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Note: the tensor is always symmetric in the mathematical sense (even if the object has no geometric symmetry). This means the written order of the indices doesn't matter: $I_{xy} = I_{yx}$, etc. That is why the inertia tensor has 6 degrees of freedom, rather than 9.

Comment: From what I can understand, this is a perfect answer, both theoretically and also practically useful. Thank you so much.

Comment: Isn't $I_{xx}$ = $I_{x}$? For example the [slender rod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia), the $I_{center}$ which I assume is $I_x$ is equal to $I_{xx}$ for the 3D case?